# Showing Different Notification on Android Device and Pebble

Tags: android, pebble-watch

When I use WhatsApp or Telegram and receive N messages, the notification on Android will show "N new messages" (and it can be expanded).

[image: On Android]

- Telegram shows notification with `contentText` "7 new messages" on Android. **I have achieved this successfully**.

However, on my Pebble Time, the last notification is the string of the last message, not "7 new messages".

[image: Telegram On Pebble]

- On Pebble, it shows the 7th (last) message (the censored part is phone number). **This is what I want**.

I am trying to develop similar feature but have not succeeded. The notification on my Android displays correctly ("N new messages") but on Pebble Time, it's identical (also "N new messages", I want it to be the Nth message).

[image: My App On Pebble]

- My app on Pebble. This is **NOT** what I want.

I have tried to call `.notify` twice (one contains "N new messages" and the other contains last message) and immediately `.cancel` the latter but Pebble Time only shows the first one.

If I don't call `.cancel` on the second notification, my Pebble will show what I want BUT there will be 2 notifications on both Android and Pebble (which I don't want).

How do I achieve similar feature like WhatsApp and Telegram?

Update:

This is the snippet I use (I have used different notification ID)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder();
...
nb.setContentText("2 new messages");
notificationManager.notify(1, nb.build());

nb.setContentText("B");
notificationManager.notify(2, nb.build());
notificationManager.cancel(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use same **id** for two notification item. you can try with different id for each show notification item.

From Android docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int, android.app.Notification)

> id: An identifier for this notification unique within your
>   application.

Comment: Hi @asdcvf, I did use different notification ID but to no avail. I have updated the original question.

Comment: why you need to call cancel() function, I think you should remove the cancel() function, so your app will display 2 notification item.

Comment: b-but...I don't want to show 2 notification item on Android. What makes me curious is WhatsApp and Telegram can do it.

Comment: did you want to group notification like whatsapp?

Comment: If there are > 1 messages, I want them to be grouped on Android. However, on Pebble, I want them to be laid out one by one (so user can read the real message instead of "N new messages"). I have successfully implemented the grouped message part but no success for the Pebble part.

Comment: I don't know what exactly that you want to show, But if you want to show only once notification item, you can use only once notification ID (the notification will be updating if has changed), and use difference notification ID if you want to display many notification item

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshot. Hope it will clear out the confusion.